# Best way to extract inline json into JS and HTML?

Tags: jquery, json

What is the best way to extract data from inline JSON into JS DOM.

```
<script id="catjson" type="application/json">
{
    "Page": [
        {
            "catfull": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "tag": "seotag1",
                    "link": "http://somelink1/",
                    "toptext": "top text 1",
                    "bottomtext": "bottom text 1",
                    "src": "http://*****/media/wysiwyg/assets/pages/timberland/middlespot1.jpg",
                    "type": "image"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "tag": "seotag2",
                    "link": "http://somelink2/",
                    "toptext": "top text 2",
                    "bottomtext": "bottom text 2",
                    "src": "http://****/media/wysiwyg/assets/pages/timberland/middlespot2.jpg",
                    "type": "image"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

I would like to extract certain elements from this JSON (such as the image src for Id 2)

I have tried:

```
var str = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('catjson').innerHTML);
console.log(str.Page.catfull.id[1].src);
```

This does not work and says that the path does not exist. This works `console.log(str.Page);` but that spits the full JSON.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with "pick out elements".

Comment: You should change `var str =` to `var stuff =`

Comment: I just want to pick or console.log any value I pick

Comment: Do you mean to stringify it, e.g: `console.log(JSON.stringify(str.Page, null ,4));`???

Comment: I have updated the question. I want to console.log the image source or any other element. Nothing to do with stringfry. Apologies I thought my question was clear.

Comment: `rather than loop elements` You cannot do that without looping in some way or explecitely specify index of element in array to extract  `console.log(str.Page[0].catfull[0].src);`

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff I would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var data = JSON.parse($("#catjson").html());
console.log(data.Page[0].catfull[0].src);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/79Lw769c/3/
here is a fiddle for you, I used jquery, btw

or in your original code just put the right indexes

```
console.log(str.Page[0].catfull[0].src);
```

Comment: So I missed Page[0] as page may have many branches; cant believe didn't see that one!

Comment: yeah, it can be easily missed

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('catjson').innerHTML);
console.log(str.Page.catfull[1].src);
```

catfull[0] is the first one (id 1), and so on.